# How can I download op-amp TL082 model?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, resistors, circuit-design, inductor

I have just started using LTSpice. I need to simulate a  Chua circuit with op amps TL082, but I did not find this operational amplifier. The reference paper which I have use that use this third party model OP-AMP TL082 of Texas instruments 2007. How can I download it?

[image]

Comment: You can use **ADTL082** from the component selection window.

Comment: You do not need to use exactly the TL082 OpAmp in Chua's circuit: you can use any of the high performance OpAmps included in LTSpice libraries. Just choose one with (MOS)FET inputs.